# How to calculate difference between dates in R?

Tags: r

My df has two columns I need to work on. I'd like to calculate difference between the two. Worked on it for half a day, without succeeding.

started_at and ended_at, here is a sample:

`started_at          ended_at 2023-09-23 00:27:50 2023-09-23 00:33:27 2023-09-02 09:26:43 2023-09-02 09:38:19 2023-09-25 18:30:11 2023-09-25 18:41:39 2023-09-13 15:30:49 2023-09-13 15:39:18 2023-09-18 15:58:58 2023-09-18 16:05:04 2023-09-15 20:19:25 2023-09-15 20:30:27`

They were char type. I managed to turned them into POSIXt:

`df$started_at <- ymd_hms(df$started_at)`

`df$ended_at <- ymd_hms(df$ended_at)`

What I need is to have the time difference between the two values. Anyone can help me please?

I tried using the following, I got: *character string is not in a standard unambiguous format*

```
difftime(scrap_3$ended_at, scrap_3$started_at, units="mins")
```

Thank you!

Comment: `df$minutes_diff = as.numeric(df$ended_at - df$started_at)/60`?

Comment: `"ended_at"` is a string, it only has human-inference relation to the same-named column in `df`, but R is not going to make that leap for you. Try `difftime(df$ended_at, df$started_at, units="mins")`. (I might be stretching a little here, though ... your sample data shows column names containing spaces but your `difftime(..)` code uses underscores instead.) If that does not work for you (still erring), please [edit] your question to include _unambiguous_ sample data by pasting the output from `dput(head(df))` into a [code block]. Thanks!

Comment: @JonSpring thank you so much! it works very fine. as you might tell, I'm a beginner.

Comment: @r2evans thank you for your answer. the code you gave me worked. I'm a beginner. I still don't understand some things. ps: i edited the sample data, apologize for that.

Comment: You only did a partial edit, please show that you actually did convert to `POSIXt` columns by adding the code you used and the output from `dput(.)` as discussed above. Without that, this is just a "typo", since you have not corrected the error of using string literals in the call to `difftime` that needs _vectors_ of objects.

Comment: @r2evans thank you for your answer. I just made an edit to show the conversion you asked. I'm not sure what I should do for the second part: adding the output from `dput(.)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lubridate` has a nice way to do this.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df <-
  data.frame(
           started_at = c("2023-09-23 00:27:50",
                          "2023-09-02 09:26:43","2023-09-25 18:30:11",
                          "2023-09-13 15:30:49","2023-09-18 15:58:58","2023-09-15 20:19:25"),
             ended_at = c("2023-09-23 00:33:27",
                          "2023-09-02 09:38:19","2023-09-25 18:41:39",
                          "2023-09-13 15:39:18","2023-09-18 16:05:04","2023-09-15 20:30:27")
         )

mutate(
  df,
  started_at = ymd_hms(started_at),
  ended_at = ymd_hms(ended_at),
  diff = ended_at - started_at
)
#>            started_at            ended_at           diff
#> 1 2023-09-23 00:27:50 2023-09-23 00:33:27  5.616667 mins
#> 2 2023-09-02 09:26:43 2023-09-02 09:38:19 11.600000 mins
#> 3 2023-09-25 18:30:11 2023-09-25 18:41:39 11.466667 mins
#> 4 2023-09-13 15:30:49 2023-09-13 15:39:18  8.483333 mins
#> 5 2023-09-18 15:58:58 2023-09-18 16:05:04  6.100000 mins
#> 6 2023-09-15 20:19:25 2023-09-15 20:30:27 11.033333 mins
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: thank you for your help. it works. despite the fact that I get the output of `diff` in secs instead of mins, any tips on that? again, thank you!

Comment: When using anything that derives from `\`-.POSIXt\`` (which includes `diff` and `difftime`), it's a best practice to always use `units=` so that you get what you expect. In this case, `as.numeric(ended_at - started_at, units="mins")`.

Comment: thank you @r2evans. I knew about using `units=`; but your explanation makes it certainly more clear to me. I was just surprised that @joshbrows got minutes despite not using `units`, whereas I got seconds.

Comment: The reason is that the rendering tries to be "smart" about it and give you units that make sense given the overall range of your returned values. For instance, it thinks it should give you days or secs depending on how close the observations are to each other. The heuristic is, as always, flawed ... or more accurately, it is _contextual_, requiring the human in the loop to interpret/verify it, or the programmer to be specific about intended units, before any form of comparison or interpretation is actually done. Glad it works for you.